# in Ruby, why I need to define a hash, but don't need to define variables?

Tags: ruby, hash

I mean, I don't declare

```
my_var = new variable
```

or something like that.
I just go with

```
my_var = 1;
```

Similarly, why can't I just

```
books["War and peace"] = :masterpiece
```

Why I need to define in advance?

```
books = {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing:

```
my_var = 1
```

Is defining and assigning the local variable. With a hash it could be done like this:

```
books = { 'War and Peace' => :masterpiece }
```

Comment: So, just to spell this out, `1` is a numeric literal, `{ 'War and Peace' => :masterpiece }` is a Hash literal. Thus both statements here have exactly the same form, as does `name = "John"` and `list = [1,2,3,4]`. It only gets more complicated if you need to create an object type for which there isn't a built-in literal syntax, like `x = Set.new([1,2,3,4])`.

Answer (score 8):

`books["War and peace"] = :masterpiece` calls the `[]=` method on `books` with `"War and peace"` and `:masterpiece` as its arguments. If `books` doesn't exist, you can't call a method on it.

Or to approach the question a different way: If ruby did do some magic to automatically initialize variables, when you use `[]=` on them, how should ruby know that you want `books` to be a hash in the above example? Any class can have `[]` and `[]=` operators which accept strings as an index.